# SFTP password wrong from remote, but not from local

Tags: linux, ssh, password, sftp

From my server, connecting to it via eth0 (not localhost), I can connect via SFTP:

```
Apr  9 10:02:40 domain sshd[11526]:
  Accepted password for test from 1.x.x.x port 45335 ssh2
```

From a remote Filezilla, I cannot connect using the same password:

```
Apr  9 10:04:25 domain sshd[11531]:
  Failed password for test from 2.x.x.x port 26714 ssh2
```

Both IP addresses are in `hosts.allow` and the SSH config is properly and setup to allow special ssh and sftp groups to connect.

What could be the error?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this and the answer is so nifty, I thought instead of discarding the question, I'm sharing the solution:

When I connected to my server using `putty` and `root` to set a new password for `test`,
the putty session used `ISO-8859-1:1998 (Latin-1, West Europe)` encoding. I've put an umlaut in the password which is multibyte in `UTF-8`, so I had to change the putty session encoding to UTF-8 and change the password again.

I was pretty sure my config is good so I came to this by accident....

Always remember when setting passwords through putty:

```
ISO täst != UTF-8 täst
```

[image]